# Cannot Change Notification Sound for Parse Notifications on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, parse-platform, notifications

I know that this question has been asked dozens of times around StackOverflow, but I have visited and applied several of their answers without getting a fix for my issue. I'm trying to simply change the notification sound when a Parse notification is received on a phone from my app.

I have overridden the Parse Push Broadcast receiver as suggested in many explanations, as shown in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.PACKAGENAME.MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.PACKAGENAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here is my overridden class, MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
package com.PACKAGENAME;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

/**
 * Created by XXX on 3/31/2016.
 */
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Testing", "Fired notification class");

        Notification n = super.getNotification(context, intent);

        n.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testsound);

        n.color = 0xFF0000FF;

        Log.d("Testing", "N equals " + n);
        Log.d("Testing", "N sound equals " + n.sound);
        Log.d("Testing", "N color equals " + n.color);

        return n;
    }
}
```

I know that this is returning the notification correctly because when I send the notification, the color is changed on the notification per the code above. However, no matter what I try, the sound played is always my phone's default notification sound.

I'm trying to get any different sound to play right now; I haven't worried about actually getting the user's ringtone through the SharedPreferences object. To test this, I placed a small MP3 file (testsound.mp3) in the res/raw folder of my app. I've tried playing this, I've tried referencing a sound on my phone, and I've tried placing an MP3 in the app's "Files" folder in my file browser on the phone - none of it will fire the changed notification.

Here are a few other ways I've changed the notification setting line above (all separate):

```
n.sound = Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/21");

Uri soundURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testsound);
n.sound = soundURI;

n.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            //+ "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/res/raw/testsound.mp3");
```

Finally, on those log statements above that return the URI - the sound always shows as "sound=default" even though the color property updates correctly (color=0xFF0000FF).

I am totally stumped. Am I missing something?